# Is a cookbook “equipment” for the Cooking skill?

Tags: magic-items, skills, equipment, gurps

Would cookbooks qualify as equipment for modifier puposes? I.e., would someone who understands cookbook terms be able to gain a modifier to their roll by using one? I.e. would a gourmet cookbook give you a bonus to gourmet cooking rolls? Furthermore would understanding the recipe give a bonus to the roll? If it does, then how much of a bonus to the roll would it give?

Some basic understanding of cookery would probably help though. I naturally mean as to improve your cooking roll of course.
I do know that Gurps magic items 2 had some enchanted cookbooks, would they (if properly enchanted) give a bonus to a cooking roll?

Comment: This is at least no longer too broad. However, it's still unclear what the problem is, since (per a previous revision) [you've asked and had this solved already](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=84750). If you could explain how [this solution](http://forums.sjgames.com/showpost.php?p=1275779&postcount=17) and [this solution](http://forums.sjgames.com/showpost.php?p=1275806&postcount=18) do not solve the problem, we might be able to better understand what the current problem is.

Comment: I just thought people would want clarity in a role playing game situations for cookbook rules.

Comment: While still learning how to use the site properly, please only ask questions that you need a solution to.

Comment: Okay @SevenSidedDie  will do if possible

Comment: What game do you ask about?

Comment: Gurps iou is the game I’m asking about mostly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on era and location, some modifiers that could come into play would include:

- equipment availability and quality of that equipment *(for example, a fully stocked, professional-grade kitchen vs. typical college apartment equipment)*
- cookbook(s)
- experienced assistant(s) or tutor(s)
- familiarity with the kitchen *(the first time in a new kitchen, just finding all the things is tricky)*
- well-stocked larder/pantry/fridge/freezer
- high-quality ingredients *(fresh seasonings instead of dried powders, or higher-quality cuts of meat instead of cheaper cuts, etc.)*
- time *(a rushed meal is more likely to have flaws than one where the cook has time to plan it out and do things in the right order)*
- complexity of the dish(es) *(pizza or spaghetti and sauce is easy. But a 3 or 4 course French dinner? That's going to be a higher challenge rating)*
- the person/people eating the food *(I can cook a darn good pot of chili. But if the consumer is a professional chili cook-off winner, s/he's going to think my chili is crap. A professional taster or chef will be more aware of even the tiniest flaw than the average diner)*
- familiarity with the recipe. *(Someone who is an expert on preparing Japanese cuisine would get a bonus on preparing Japanese food, and possibly a bonus on some other similar Asian dishes. But wouldn't necessarily get any bonuses on preparing Mexican food...)*
- Training on equipment available. *(Stick me in a true, professional-grade kitchen and I would be lost... And any trained chef of today would likely be hard pressed to master cooking in medieval Europe's standard kitchens)*
- practice *(Cooking in general; okay that's a skill. But spend your entire career as a chef making one signature food, and you're going to get all kinds of bonuses on* that *food above and beyond your skill rating. See competitive chefs in various categories like chili cook-offs or BBQ cook-offs.)*

That's by no means an exhaustive list, but it should give you something to start with.